# Matrix with only one invariant factor

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix over the field $F$ with only one invariant factor. Show any $n \times n$ matrix $B$ over $F$ that commutes with $A$ is a polynomial in $A$.

Comment: Any $n \times n$ matrix commutes with the identity matrix, and yet the only polynomials in the identity matrix are the scalar multiples of the identity matrix...

Comment: Does this hold? If $A$ is the identity matrix, then it commutes with all the matrices, but polynomials in $A$ are all scalar. Also $1$ is the sole invariant factor of $A$. Not that invariant factors make much sense over a field. Undoubtedly you mean something else (and should not mention a key assumption in the title alone anyway).

Comment: It might be a matter of wording, but I take the assumption to mean that the underlying vector space is a cyclic $F[A]$-module.

Comment: In other words, all invariant factor *but one* are $1$.

Comment: @Andreas: So you are talking about the invariant factors of $xI-A$ as opposed to $A$? That does make the question meaningful. Well decpihered :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, right, thanks, let me spell this out in my answer, with credit where it's due ;-)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, just noticed you let that oldish question come back to the surface.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Yes, I changed its title to be more informative

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think the [invariant factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_factor) in the question is to be interpreted is the one of $F^n$ as $F[X]$ module, with $X$ acting by $A$; see [modules over a PID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modules_over_a_pid#Invariant_factor_decomposition). In fact I don't see many other modules over a PID here.

Comment: @Marc: I quite agree! Feeling a bit silly for not realizing it right away.

Comment: I think this is an edge case where a Question narrowly avoids being a duplicate by being confused.  Does it make sense to leave it open essentially for the value of sorting out what the Question really means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take the assumption to mean that the underlying vector space $V$ is a cyclic $F[A]$-module. (*Only one invariant factor of $x I - A$ is different from $1$.* Thanks to Jyrki Lahtonen for a clarifying remark in a comment to OP.)

Suppose $v_{0}$ is a generator of $V$ as such a $F[A]$-module. Then $v_{0} B = v_{0} f(A)$ for some polynomial $f \in F[x]$ (apologies, my operators act on the right).

Now given any $v \in V$, there is $g \in F[x]$ such that $v = v_{0} g(A)$. Thus
$$
v B = v_{0} g(A) B = v_{0} B g(A) = v_{0} f(A) g(A) = v_{0} g(A) f(A) = v f(A).
$$
It follows $B = f(A)$.